Can`t install ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS in my virtualbox 7.1.4
Oct 17 10:33:41 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Get:93 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Oct 17 10:33:41 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Err:9 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Oct 17 10:33:41 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]:   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Oct 17 10:33:41 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Ign:9 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Oct 17 10:33:42 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Err:9 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Oct 17 10:33:42 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]:   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Oct 17 10:33:42 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Ign:9 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Oct 17 10:33:42 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Err:9 http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages
Oct 17 10:33:42 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]:   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Oct 17 10:33:43 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Fetched 27.8 MB in 35s (801 kB/s)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: Reading package lists...
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: E: Failed to fetch http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5031]: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.008
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['umount', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['umount', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['umount', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['umount', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: Running command ['umount', '/tmp/tmpnubhqo2t/mount/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_log.3545[5018]: finish: cmd-in-target: FAIL: curtin command in-target
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_event.3545[3545]: configuring apt
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_event.3545[3545]: 
Oct 17 10:33:44 ubuntu subiquity_event.3545[3545]:  curtin command in-target


The errors "Failed to fetch http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]" look strange. Do you have a strange web proxy? Are you in a company network? How did you configure the networking of the virtual machine? Please [edit] your question to add this information.
Or did you try again at a later time in case this might have been a temporary problem with this package mirror? Or choose a different mirror?

This question is similar to: Upgrade to 18.04: "failed to fetch" 403 Forbidden Error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
